# How do I get all the rows meeting some criteria out of a big matrix?

Tags: performance, matlab, if-statement, for-loop, matrix

I have a big matrix (on the order of 1GB) where each row represents the (x,y) coordinate of a point I sampled a surface at, and its z-height.

How do I get all the points less than some euclidean distance away from the (x,y) coordinate?

Currently I am doing this awful thing:

```
% mtx_pointList is a large matrix with each row containing a sample: [x y z]. 
% We want to get all the samples whose (x,y) point is less than dDistance 
%   away from the vector: v_center = [x y].
```

mtx_regionSamples = zeros(0,3);
for k=1:length(mtx_pointList(:,1))
    if( norm( mtx_pointList(k,[1 2])-v_center ) < dDistance^2 )
            mtx_regionSamples = [ mtx_regionSamples mtx_pointList(k,:) ]
    end
end

...but in my application this loop would have to be run around 250k times.

How do I make it do the same thing faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist2.html) (its default option is Euclidean distance):

```
ind = pdist2(mtx_pointList(:,[1 2]), v_center) < dDistance; %// logical index
result = mtx_pointList(ind,:);
```

If the matrix is too large, divide it into chunks of as many rows as your memory allows, and loop over the chunks.

Answer (score 3):

### bsxfun

If you don't have `pdist2` (statistics toolbox), here's one way to compute distances with `bsxfun`:

```
da = bsxfun(@minus,mtx_pointList(:,[1 2]),permute(v_center,[3 2 1]));
distances = sqrt(sum(da.^2,2));
```

Then find point that meet your criteria:

```
distThresh = 0.5; % for example
indsClose = distances < distThresh
result = mtx_pointList(indsClose,:);
```

### alternative

You can also use an alternate form of Euclidean (2-norm) distance,

```
||A-B|| = sqrt ( ||A||^2 + ||B||^2 - 2*A.B )
```

In MATLAB code:

```
a = mtx_pointList(:,[1 2]); b = v_center;
aa = dot(a,a,2); bb = dot(b,b,2); ab=a*b.'; %' or sum(a.*a,2)
distances = sqrt(aa + bb - 2*ab); % bsxfun needed if b is more than one point
```

As Luis Mendo points out, the `sqrt` is not necessary if you threshold against `distThresh^2`.

Comment: +1 It would be slighlty more efficient to remove the `sqrt` and compare against distThresh^2

Comment: @LuisMendo Good suggestion (again!).

Comment: See? It's not that bad :-P